# Django+Celery Module not found error with app installed from git

Tags: python, django, docker, celery, django-celery

I'm have a project split on 2 separate apps and both have another shared app as reusable one(i store my models there and install it from git link.
So when i run celery worker locally all is working perfect, but if i use docker(with celery in separate image) i got this error

```
Error: 
celery_api           | Unable to load celery application.
celery_api           | The module common was not found.
```

In some reason celery gets improper configuration from django.

celery docker config

```
celery_api:
    image: celery_api
    container_name: celery_api
    restart: unless-stopped
    build: .
    command: celery worker -A djookyapi --loglevel=info
    env_file:
      - ./.dev.env
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
    networks:
      - dev
```

celery file in the root of project folder(near settings.py file)

```
__future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

import os
import sys

from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
sys.path.append(BASE_DIR)
# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproj.settings')
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_CONFIGURATION', 'Local')

import configurations

configurations.setup()

app = Celery('myproj', )

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

So why celery doesn't see my app?

Comment: Did you solve it? I have a same proble

Comment: @user3595632 did you manage to solve this facing the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed config in docker-compose like this:

```yaml
  celery_api:
    image: celery_api:latest
    container_name: celery_api
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: ./
    command: celery worker -A djookyapi --loglevel=info -B
    env_file:
      - ./.dev.env
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
    networks:
      - dev
```